# Grid with lots of information - do not show when empty

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have a very large grid, where I am showing some of my XAML below, but it should not show the Textblockes on the row, if the value is empty. 
How can I create that?

```
<Grid x:Name="JobDetailGrid">
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Uid="JobDetailTaskType" />
   <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" x:Uid="JobDetailTaskTypeSrv" Text="{Binding TaskType}" />
   <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" x:Uid="JobDetailStatus" />
   <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" x:Uid="JobDetailStatusSrv" Text="{Binding Status}" />
   <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" x:Uid="JobDetailApproved" />
   <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" x:Uid="JobDetailApprovedSrv" Text="{Binding Approved}" />
```

Perhaps I could do it in C#, but I am thinking, if I could make a Binding or create a StackPanel, but the problem with StackPanel as I see it, is that I need to create margin after each TextBlock

Or do I need to create my own User-Control for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can easily be done via binding! You need to create a [converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter.aspx) that will take a string, and return a visibility (so empty string will hide the text box), then set the visibility of the textblock as follows:-

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Uid="JobDetailTaskType" Visibility={Binding TaskType, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}}/>
```

Place the visibility on both the textblock's (the label and the value), and since you have the height to auto you shouldn't need to mess about with margins.

Comment: Is the row also hidden then?

Comment: Yes, since its set to auto - Do you not want it hidden?

Comment: If there are no value, yes